# Having a G Form Script create a new tab to report to in G Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a form where it reports monthly to a sheet. But I want it to automatically create a new tab in the sheet for the next month. So if it is current reporting to the December tab on the 1st of January it will automatic trigger to create the new tab and start importing the data there. I already have a script running where it pulls data from a gsheet for a drop down and refreshes itself via a trigger every min.

Comment: Try searching for insertSheet():https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet